# jquery with php and laravel Copying select option values from one element line item and pasting them to the next

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I am trying to get the values in the selected option and apply them from one element to the next.  one element may have up to 8 options to select from. i also only want the first 4 of those 8 applied to elements that can only accept 4.

```
   <select name="b{{$n}}[]">
   <option value="{{$b['name']}}">{{$b['name']}}</option>

$('.copyANDpaste').on("click", function(event) {
        var allBrands = $('.brands<?=$n?>');
        
        $(".brands<?=$n?> option").each(function() { 
            var option = new Option($(this).text(), $(this).val());
            $(option).html($(this).text());
            $(this).append(option);
        });
```

do not think append will work - its adding the text to the same brand name line in select dropdown

Comment: you are in loop of options, so if you use this, you point to current option and append another option to it, maybe something like $(this).parent().append(option) could work? or give me more details what you want to achieve

Comment: yes so instead of the select reading "select one" it changes to "select oneselect one".  $(this).parent().appent(option) didnt work. there is one row for a product. user can select 4 different brands for one prod,  each in own select dropdwn   i want to take those 4 selected brands and apply them to the next product (thus the next row).  it also needs to work where if the user selects 8 brands, but the product only allows 4, only 4 are applied. once one product has its brands selected, click a button that says "apply to all", and it will auto fill in the rest of the product rows select options

Comment: can you provide some picture of webpage?

Comment: as I understand your description, you will need parent element, where you will append the new Option, currently you are append it to this, and that is wrong. So for each select you can add data attribute, something like data-related="id_for_new_row_select" and then you can easily get that from parent of selected option id= $(this).parent().data('related'), then you should be able call append method on that element $('#'+id).append(option)

Comment: get the .data('related') just that way?  not having luck. appreciate the help.

Comment: should work, you have to call it on jQuery object https://api.jquery.com/data/